# How to compare two tables in linq to sql?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to compare two tables (i.e values, count, etc..) in linq to sql but I am not getting the way to achieve it. I tried the following,

```
Table1.Any(i => i.itemNo == Table2.itemNo)
```

It gives error. Could you please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am trying to achieve it in a boolean function. Based on comparison I want to return true or false if values or count matches.

Comment: What exactly are you comparing? Does the data in the tables have to be identical?

Comment: Yes the data in the tables have to be identical and even the count of rows should match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about

```
var isDifferent =
        Table1.Zip(Table2, (j, k) => j.itemNo == k.itemMo).Any(m => !m);
```

---

**EDIT**

if Linq-To-Sql does not support Zip.

```
var one = Table1.ToList();
var two = Table2.ToList();

var isDifferent =
        one.Zip(two, (j, k) => j.itemNo == k.itemMo).Any(m => !m);
```

if the tables are vary large this could cause performance problems. In that case you will need a much more sophisticated solution, if so, please ask.

**EDIT2**

If the tables are very large you don't want to get all the data from the server and hold it memory. Additionaly, Linq and SQL server do not garauntee the order of the rows unless you specify an order in the query. This becomes espcially relavent for large result sets returned by a multi processor server where the effects of parallelism are likely to come into play.

I suggest that Linq-to-Sql doesen't really cater well for your scenario so you will have to help it out using [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109) somthing like this.

```
string zipQuery =
@"SELECT TOP 1
        1
    FROM
        [Table1] [one]
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM [Table2] [two] WHERE [two].[itemNo] = [one].[itemNo]
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT
        1
    FROM
        [Table2] [two]
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM [Table1] [one] WHERE [one].[itemNo] = [two].[itemNo]
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT 0";

var isDifferent = context.ExecuteQuery<int>(zipQuery).Single() == 1;
```

This will do the select on the server without returning lots of data to the client but, I think you will agree is much more complicated.

---

**EDIT3**

Okay, the zip approach should be fine for 1000 rows. I've read your comment and I suggest changing the code accordingly.

```
var one = Table1.ToList();
var two = Table2.ToList();

var isDifferent =
    one.Count != two.Count ||
    one.Zip(two, (o, t) => o.itemNo == k.itemNo).Any(m => !m);
```

You should probably consider putting an order by on the list retrievers, like this.

```
var one = Table1.OrderBy(o => o.itemNo).ToList();
```

Strictly, the results of a Linq-to-Sql come back in any order unless an order is specified.

Comment: How to use it in if statement

Comment: Your code is fine but I cannot use it in my if statement to return true or false based on the result.

Comment: The return type of the above statement is a boolean so just put `if` before it and some brackets and there you have it in an if statement...

Comment: Actually I had missed out ')' in my if statement.

Comment: I am getting error - NotSupportedException: The query operator 'Zip' is not supported.

Comment: Ok, maybe its not supported with Linq-To-Sql.

Comment: Is there any similar method in Linq-To-Sql.

Comment: @JavedAhmed how large, `1000` rows `1000000` rows?

Comment: It is large like 1000 rows. I tried zip. It is executing fine. But it is not comparing correctly. I want to know if tables are matching exactly. If I add new row or even duplicate row it should give false. But it is not.

Comment: Jodrell! Zip method loops from first data to last data and again to first data. I don't want to loop it again to first data. How to do that?

Comment: @JavedAhmed, sorry, I don't understand, `Zip` will iterate through two `IEnumerable`s in tandem. It uses lazy evaluation so because of the `Any` will only be evaluated as far as the first non matching couplet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jodrell. The if(one.Count != two.Count || one.Zip(two, (j, k) => j.itemNo == k.Item_No).Any(m => !m)) goes to else part. So what i have done is on the else part I am assigning true. That's my workaround.